# Measure performance of the queries and execution functions

Tags: php, database, performance, laravel

Is there any way - some module/plugin in Laravel, which measures time of executing funtions, queries and and **number of requests** and gives me some data about this? For example like **Ruby on Rails logger**?

If this exists, how to use It please?

In Ruby, when I this:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])
    logger.debug "New article: #{@article.attributes.inspect}"
    logger.debug "Article should be valid: #{@article.valid?}"

    if @article.save
      flash[:notice] =  'Article was successfully created.'
      logger.debug "The article was saved and now the user is going to be redirected..."
      redirect_to(@article)
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

And it gives this:

```
Processing ArticlesController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2008-09-08 11:52:54) [POST]
  Session ID: BAh7BzoMY3NyZl9pZCIlMDY5MWU1M2I1ZDRjODBlMzkyMWI1OTg2NWQyNzViZjYiCmZsYXNoSUM6J0FjdGl
vbkNvbnRyb2xsZXI6OkZsYXNoOjpGbGFzaEhhc2h7AAY6CkB1c2VkewA=--b18cd92fba90eacf8137e5f6b3b06c4d724596a4
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create", "article"=>{"title"=>"Debugging Rails",
 "body"=>"I'm learning how to print in logs!!!", "published"=>"0"},
 "authenticity_token"=>"2059c1286e93402e389127b1153204e0d1e275dd", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"articles"}
New article: {"updated_at"=>nil, "title"=>"Debugging Rails", "body"=>"I'm learning how to print in logs!!!",
 "published"=>false, "created_at"=>nil}
Article should be valid: true
  Article Create (0.000443)   INSERT INTO "articles" ("updated_at", "title", "body", "published",
 "created_at") VALUES('2008-09-08 14:52:54', 'Debugging Rails',
 'I''m learning how to print in logs!!!', 'f', '2008-09-08 14:52:54')
The article was saved and now the user is going to be redirected...
Redirected to # Article:0x20af760>
Completed in 0.01224 (81 reqs/sec) | DB: 0.00044 (3%) | 302 Found [http://localhost/articles]
```

Thank you for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) installed, then you can use following functions.

```
xdebug_start_trace( '/path/to/trace/file.log' );
xdebug_stop_trace();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)